# Displaying a character as a decimal number with cout

Tags: c++

In the C programming language, I can use `printf` to display a character and its decimal equivalent with code like this

```
char c='e';
printf( "decimal value: %d   char value: %c\n",c,c);
```

How can I do the same in C++ using `cout`? For example, the following code displays the character, but how would I get `cout` to print the decimal value?

```
char c='e';
cout << c;
```

Comment: Why `C` language tag?

Answer (score 14):

```
cout << +c;
```

Unary `+` cast operator will implicitly convert `char` to `int`.

[Demo here](http://ideone.com/FWV5DJ)

From **5.3.1 Unary operators** aka expr.unary.op

> [7] The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic,
>   unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the result is the value of
>   the argument. **Integral promotion** is performed on integral or
>   enumeration operands. The type of the result is the type of the
>   promoted operand.

Further readings:

- [cppreference > Utilities Library > Type support > std::is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) to understand the meaning of integral types.
- [cppreference > C++ > C++ Language > Expressions > Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) > Numeric promotions > Integral promotion

Comment: Love this answer, because this let's me use the same function body for all template arguments `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`!

Comment: @mxmlnkn Thanks. I am glad that you liked it.

Answer (score 8):

The best C++ way to cast `c` to `int` is `static_cast< int >( c )`.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the character to an int to obtain the decimal value in C++, like

```
char c='e';
std::cout << "Decimal : " << (int)c << std::endl;
std::cout << "Char : " << c;
```

By doing `(int)c` , you can temporarily convert it to an int and get the decimal value.

This process is known as [type casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

Comment: A C style cast, really?